# Getting coordinates for locations from Google Map?

Tags: google-maps

I wonder is it possible to get coordinates (of pins) from Google Map which is integrated in some website?

Comment: It would be helpful to the community if you provide an example website in which you are interested in data-mining these coordinate(pins) locations.

Comment: @MichaelMarkieta, for example http://maps.google.com/! It has always been a problem to get the coordinates from there!

Comment: @Thomas can you check my answer to see if this is helpful. There are times when a google map has been created using the api and there are markers on the map which you want information about. Instead of trying to right click on ever marker, we can check each markers source code location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

View the page's source code and see if they are being publicly published.
For example: http://www.canada411.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/mcdonalds%20restaurant/Toronto%2C%20ON?showDD=true

If you view the source code on that page, you will be able to find the lat + long of each pushpin marker on the google maps map. Also, each record holds information about its lat + long regardless of it being shown on the map itself. Each webpage will be uniquely formatted. Some poking around in the source code may reveal a lot of information about the data to the user!

Near the bottom of the source:

```
    pushpinLocals[0] = new Array();
    pushpinLocals[0][0] = 43.732648;
    pushpinLocals[0][1] = -79.404175;
    pushpinLocals[0][2] = "<a href=\"javascript:getListingLink(1)\"  style='font-weight: bold;'>McDonalds Restaurants Inc</a>";
    pushpinLocals[0][3] = "3400 Yonge";
    pushpinLocals[0][4] = "Toronto, ON, M4N2M7";
    pushpinLocals[0][7] = "<br /><b>416-481-8779</b>";
    pushpinLocals[0][8] = customIconSpecification;
```

Comment: That is the right solution. I entered in the source code and find all coordinates I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Within Google Maps, right-clicking anywhere and then clicking "What's here?" on the contextual menu should return coordinates for the spot you clicked.

Comment: Yes, or "Drop LatLng Marker" on context menu. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the data is loaded from a webservice , Google Chrome has a really cool tool for network petitions.
You just have to open the Developers Tool with F12 and navigate to the NETWORK tab and then without closing it, reload the page.
Once the page has been reloaded just go to the XHR tab at the bottom of the popoup window and you'll be able to see all the petitions and the response.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you go to **https://google.com/maps/search/[Address]** it redirects to a url with required coordinates in it, just get that url